# Globalization uiCulture is not applied during ASP.NET startup

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization, web-config

I want to configure some bundles based on the uiCulture during the startup of the asp.net via owin. I have this in my web.config

```
<system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="nb-NO" culture="nb-NO"/>
</system.web>
```

What happens is that `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` set properly, but `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` is not. I have checked that both properties are fine during the controller action. Is there a way I can read they UI culture during startup and why is it not loading at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx) on MSDN.

Quoting an example from the site:

```
<globalization uiCulture="es" culture="es-MX" />
```

So in your case, maybe you can try this:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="nb" culture="nb-NO"/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: I tried that and it did not work. I guess it is set properly since it does really work in the controller, but not during startup...